# Make Templates for basic data types only

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

How can we make a template accept only basic data types.

```
template <typename T> 
void GetMaxValue( T& x ) 
{ 
//... Finds max Value
}
```

In the above function `GetMaxValue` we are able to pass ***any*** value without any an error.

But the std Function `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` has handled it. 
For example:

```
auto max = std::numeric_limits< std::map<int,int> >::max();
```

will Give an error `error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>'`

Comment: What is the behavior you want the compiler to exhibit? It looks like it's already preventing unwanted types.

Comment: You can use template specialization to exhaustively cover all data types. Since you already noticed that some standard facility does this, you could try to look at how those are implemented. See e.g. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/limits

Comment: See the example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral   and if required add a few more `is_xxx` from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With constraints in C++20:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <class T> 
requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
void GetMaxValue( T& x ) 
{ 
//... Finds max Value
}
```

Usage:

```
int a = 0;
GetMaxValue(a); // fine

std::vector<int> b;
GetMaxValue(b); // compiler error
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V0rzJoCn51DRVgOJ)

---

With `std::enable_if` otherwise:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0> 
void GetMaxValue( T& x ) 
{ 
//... Finds max Value
}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zvqjuio0lcBKuSa9)

---

The error messages pre-constraints are harder to read:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'GetMaxValue(std::vector<int>&)'
  |     GetMaxValue(b); // compiler error
  |                  ^
Note: candidate: 'template<class T, typename std::enable_if<is_arithmetic_v<T>, int>::type <anonymous> > void GetMaxValue(T&)'
  | void GetMaxValue( T& x )
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
  | template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0>
  |                                                                     ^
In instantiation of 'void GetMaxValue(T&) [with T = int; typename std::enable_if<is_arithmetic_v<T>, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]'
```

vs

```
error: cannot call function 'void GetMaxValue(T&) [with T = std::vector<int>]'
  |     GetMaxValue(b); // compiler error
  |                  ^
note: constraints not satisfied
In function 'void GetMaxValue(T&) [with T = std::vector<int>]':
    required by the constraints of 'template<class T>  requires  is_arithmetic_v<T> void GetMaxValue(T&)'
note: the expression 'is_arithmetic_v<T>' evaluated to 'false'
  | requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
  |          ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```